# openpyxl LineChart appears empty after adding reference to values

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have the following code to create a line chart in Excel using openpyxl. The problem is that when the excel file is generated, the chart container is added to the worksheet, but it is empty and no chart is displayed. I've checked the reference object and looks fine. Any idea of what could be causing this?

```
c1 = LineChart()
c1.title = "Line Chart"
c1.style = 10
c1.y_axis.title = 'Utilization'
c1.x_axis.title = 'Month'

data = Reference(worksheet, min_col = 2, min_row = 2, max_col = 2, max_row = 10)
print(data) #this prints Sheet 1!$B$2:$B$10
c1.add_data(data)
worksheet.add_chart(c1, "E2")
```

Comment: Is there actually any data in the range B2:B10?

Comment: Yes, actually the populated range is much bigger, but I'm testing with a smaller set with no success.

Comment: Everything looks okay but it's difficult to say much without a file. You might want to continue the discussion on the mailing list.

Comment: I must clarify that the chart space is completely blank, just a white rectangle, not axis are displayed. If i were to select an empty data range, the axis and labels would appear, right? So my guess is that maybe I'm missing some call to a function to "refresh" the chart, since the chart is there and when I click the select data option and select the range, the chart shows perfectly with the configured titles and proper values.

Comment: No point in speculating. You'll need to look at the source of the file to find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I had very similar issue with openpyxl. It turned out to be a hyphen character ('-') in the worksheet name which used later in the x and y data reference for series. I replaced the hyphen with underscore ('_') character and it worked.
In your case replace the space in the worksheet name, or add single quotes before and after sheet name, i.e. 'Sheet 1'

Comment: Looks like this bug with spaces was fixed (at least it works for me), but there is another one: you couldn't add charts if you have unicode symbols in sheet name (for example cyrillic symbols).

https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/548/unicode-support-in-charts - here is an old fixed issue, I've tried to attract maintainer's attention.

Comment: On a related note, I found the exact same problem when the sheet name is just a number. Appending a character to the sheet name fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
ws = wb.create_sheet(title = work_sheet_name.replace('-', '_'))
```